# Помощь по c# с запросами

Tags: c#, xnet

Добрые люди, помогите решить такой вопрос. При отправке POST-запроса на сервер, для проверки авторизации, приходится менять знаки "@" на "%40" и просто так user@mail.com уже не написать. Как можно сделать так, чтобы я вносил в логин вид user@mail.com, а он мне сам менял знак @ на %40. ?

Answer (score 1):

- [WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/73z22y6h(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: В каком месте здесь ее нужно вставить? И как выглядит код? Я только начинающий ;)

https://i.gyazo.com/3ad2c96ec96dac71604fe540923d5cac.png

Comment: У вас две функции: закодировать строку и раскодировать строку. Кодируете до передачи, а декодируете после получения.

Comment: Мне нужно кодировать получается поле string login, string password ?